# "querySelectorAll" on HTML table not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I have a task to use querySelectorAll on the HTML table tr elements using nth-child to print different colors for both even and odd numbers but only the even is working. My code below

I'm also getting the error that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined",

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Numbers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>1 = odd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2 = even</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>3 = odd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>4 = even</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick='execute()'>Execute</button>
</body>
<script>
    function execute() {
        // your code goes here
    var odd = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:nth-child(odd)")
    var even = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:nth-child(even)")
for(i = 0; i<= odd.length; i++){
  odd[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
for(i = 0; i<= even.length; i++){
  even[i].style.backgroundColor = "green"
}
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `i < odd.length` instead of `i <= odd.length` (and the same change for the evens). `length` is going to be last index plus one because array indices are zero-based.

Overrunning the end of the array causes an error, which stops execution so you don't see any of the changes that otherwise would've followed.

Works with just those changes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Numbers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>1 = odd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2 = even</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>3 = odd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>4 = even</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick='execute()'>Execute</button>
</body>
<script>
    function execute() {
        // your code goes here
    var odd = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:nth-child(odd)")
    var even = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:nth-child(even)")
for(i = 0; i< odd.length; i++){
  odd[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
for(i = 0; i< even.length; i++){
  even[i].style.backgroundColor = "green"
}
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't vote because I have less than 15 reputations

Comment: Pretty sure you can still mark it as the accepted answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I just got to know this

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the loop condition: by using `<=`, you tell JS to iterate from 0 to the value equal to `odd.length`. However, there is nothing at `odd[odd.length]`, because its indices range from 0 to `odd.length - 1`, since arrays are 0-indexed. This is why you get the error that you're seeing - non-existent array elements always evaluate to `undefined`, whose properties cannot be referred to.

Since the first loop throws an error, JavaScript ends execution and never gets to the second loop. This is why the "even" rows aren't working.

Comment: Thank you. I can't vote because I have less than 15 reputations